# Style Selectbox option in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to  show user name and email on option of select box:

```
<option>Adda adda@example.com</option>
```

Now the issue I face is some names are larger and look weird when looking at the options.

So I tried to put `<span>` with style property in inside the option but it didn't work.

Can anyone tell me how can I put the `name` and should come on one side while the `email` goes on other side without doesn't touching each other.

Comment: `didn't work` is not a valid problem description. Show us your CSS. Make a JSFiddle as well

Comment: option tag cannot be modified by css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `option` is styled is down to the browser and you won't be able to get consistent results using css. You could use an alternative like [`select2`](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) if you want more control over the style. Note that this may affect usability on mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use html tags inside select options , you need to use something like [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want   or

So a fixed version of your example could be...

```
 <select>
 <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;Sample</option>
 </select>
```

or

```
 <select>
 <option>&#160;&#160;Sample</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Thanks for message.But i am doing dynamic results so static spaces will not fulfill that.